# GCF Node10 deploy failed: "Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Provided code is not a loadable module."

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

After making some adjustments (a rather big PR), which basically adds Google Cloud Storage connection to this function, deployment starts to fail. Unfortunately, the error message is pretty unclear and therefore doesn't provide me in much hint. Locally and in tests things run fine, so I'm a bit lost right now which direction to search. Logs don't provide insights either.

Can't really easily share the changes in the PR unfortunately. Worst case I'll revert and go piece by piece from there, but that's a tedious process.

The service account that is used in the deployment got access to the used bucket (with write), but I also don't think this error hints to permissions else I hope the error message would be more insightful.

Command used:

`gcloud beta functions deploy eventStreamPostEvent --runtime nodejs10 --memory 128MB --trigger-http --source ./dist --service-account $DEPLOY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT --verbosity debug`

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
..............................failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Provided code is not a loadable module.
Could not load the function, shutting down.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 985, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 231, in Run
    enable_vpc_connector=True)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 175, in _Run
    return api_util.PatchFunction(function, updated_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 300, in CatchHTTPErrorRaiseHTTPExceptionFn
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 356, in PatchFunction
    operations.Wait(op, messages, client, _DEPLOY_WAIT_NOTICE)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 126, in Wait
    _WaitForOperation(client, request, notice)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 101, in _WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=SLEEP_MS)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 219, in RetryOnResult
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 65, in _GetOperationStatus
    raise exceptions.FunctionsError(OperationErrorToString(op.error))
FunctionsError: OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Provided code is not a loadable module.
Could not load the function, shutting down.

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Provided code is not a loadable module.
Could not load the function, shutting down.
```

I hope anyone knows what is causing this error.

Stackdriver logs show me nothing more than:

```
 protoPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {…}   
  methodName:  "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction"   
  requestMetadata: {
   destinationAttributes: {…}    
   requestAttributes: {…}    
  }
  resourceName:  "projects/<projectName>/locations/europe-west1/functions/eventStreamPostEvent"   
  serviceName:  "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code:  3    
   message:  "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
 }
```

Comment: 1) Specify --entry-point so that Cloud Functions knows where to start your code. 2) What feature requires using the beta features of gcloud? Meaning don't call the beta feature if the non-beta supports the feature. 3) Edit your question and include your code.

Comment: 1) The entrypoint is similar as before (which also worked) and identical to the function name. 2) Node 10 + Specifying the service account under which the function should run is a beta feature. 3) Changelog is huge, so hoping someone recognises this error. Else I'll break it down obviously to debug more in depth. It would be great if the error message is more descriptive obviously.

Comment: Debugging a bit further leads me into thinking there is an error downloading the CF from the temporary cloud storage location where it parks the files before deployment. That's an internal Google thing though, but I'll try to debug it.

Comment: Try zipping the package and copying to gs://. Then retry using Cloud Storage as the source.

Comment: Could you deploy successfully with the suggestion in @JohnHanley 's comment?

Comment: Currently we've narrowed it down that it happens when the `test` folder is inside the distributed folder, even though the test folder is mentioned in .cloudignore and debug shows it's ignoring it..

Comment: What's in the `test` folder? Also, have you changed the dependencies or the nodejs version since the last deployment?

Comment: Regarding `.gcloudignore`, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy#--source) it says " _When_ [and only when] _deploying source from the local filesystem, this command_ [gcloud beta functions deploy] _skips files specified in the `.gcloudignore`_ " and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) that " _If there is a file called_ `.gcloudignore` _**in the top-level directory to upload**, the files that it specifies (see "SYNTAX") will be ignored._  "

Comment: Dependencies are equal. I see in the debug (I'm deploying from local) that it's actually ignoring the test folder. There's basically tests in it, haven't figured out yet which of the files or which part of the files might be offending. We've adjusted the flow now to not include the tests at all in the distribution folder.

Comment: I get this too but can't spot a pattern for what the cause is.  It goes away after a while.  It affects my functions seemingly randomly.  Some days they all get deployed without a problem, other days one or two get into this state and I can't figure out a way to fix it other than wait for a bit.

Comment: Can you run `gcloud components update` to see if the issue is related to the version of the Cloud SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and seems the message comes from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/src/invoker.ts).

When you have multiple .js files with some subfolders in the root folder of your function, by default without any specification you need to name the entry module as index.js or function.js.

I found that by deploying the function using node8. The error messages should be clearer...

Answer (score 1):

Usually (or; for me) the cause of OperationError: code=3 is an error in importing the modules you have defined.

Fixed this by:

1. deleting node_modules
   `rm -r .\node_modules\`
2. *optional:* you can do `npm i` after deleting node_modules and test your function locally before deploying.
3. then deleting `.gcloudignore` and deploying as usual.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by having installed one of my node_modules in the wrong directory (.. - up one dir). Make sure all of your node_modules needed are in the right place. This can easily happen if you have multiple functions in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code must contain an entry point function that has been correctly specified in your deployment, either via Cloud console or Cloud SDK.
Source: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#entry-point